# Incorrect syntax near '*='?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i'm having trouble figuring out why the following simple tsql update returned with an error

```
Incorrect syntax near '*='
```

SQL:

```
update unidb.dbo.result 
set sra = 'A'
```

- sra(char(1),null)
- sra is not part of the primary key

Comment: The error message says that there's a `*` character before `=`. Check your code.

Comment: Is that the whole code?

Comment: That's the exact whole code. No more no less... and there is no '*' added before '='. Oddly enough, it seems the statement were executed successfully; the results are correct(ie all sra updated to 'A'). I tried this on both MSSQL Server 2008R2 and the latest 2014 Management Studio, returning same incorrect syntax near '*=' error... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that `UPDATE` is the only statement that generate this error then you have triggers on  `dbo.result` and one of these triggers contains this kind of join: `*=` which means [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) (see section "Left outer join").

Solutions:

1) Set database compatibility level SQL Server 2000 (if you can; but starting from SQL Server 2012 - `SELECT @@VERSION` - the minimum database compatibility level is SQL Server 2005) or (better)

2) Replace the source code `*=` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: indeed there are two triggers but i can't find any *= in them. And I failed to alter the database compatibility level to 80... valid values are 100, 110, or 120

Comment: `dbo.result` is a table or a view ? Maybe those triggers innsert / update / delete data from another tables / views. Check if you have triggers on those objects.

Comment: dbo.result is a table... yes maybe those triggers from another tables/views caused the problem... let me check it later. Bogdan, thanks for your reply!